# jest-mock-extended set property to undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, jest-mock-extended

Hi is to possible to set a mocked property to undefined somehow?

Interface I want to mock:

```js
export interface IEmail {
  from: string | undefined;
  body: string;
  to: string;
}
```

Code I want to test:

```js
async function sendEmail(emailData: IEmail): Promise<void> {
  await this.send({
    emailBody: emailData.body,
    emailBodyFrom: emailData.from || "default_email@mail.com",
    emailTo: emailData.to,
  });
}
```

The test:

```
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';


it('should send email', async () => {
    const options = mock<IEmail>({});
  options.from = undefined
  options.to = 'jane.doe@gmail.com'
  mockemailService.send.mockResolvedValueOnce("");
  await emailService.sendEmail(options);
  expect(mockemailService.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    from: 'default_email@mail.com',
    to: 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
  });
});
```

I expect this the send function to have been called with `default_email@mail.com` but instead it has been called with a mock function causing the test to fail. How can I forcefully set the property from to undefined?

Comment: Why is that a mock at all? Just pass a regular object.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. This is just an example, the actual interface is much much bigger hence the reason for me to mock it instead of assigning mock data to every field.

Comment: Then you might want to rethink the design, e.g. apply the interface segregation principle. It should be easy enough to write functions like `createThing(relevant: Partial<Thing>): Thing`.